# using optionmenu in tkinter (python 3.3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a very simple interface with tkinter (which I'm still just learning). basically I've found that there I can use optionmenu to get a drop down menu with some given options (lets call them OP1, OP2 and OP3). What I want is that it can count for how much time the options are selected and save it to list that looks like this:

```
[['OP1',12.5],['OP2',15.35]]
```

So that I can save it on a csv file later, I don't mind the time being in seconds because i can convert it later, if this was regular code with no interface I know I could something like:

```
start = time.time()
a=input("Press Enter to switch...")
end = time.time()
b= (end - start)
```

Or something similar, please let me know if you have any ideas and keep in mind I'm on Python 3.3. :)

Thanks in advance!!!

Update:

I did this (with a lot of internet help of course):

```
from tkinter import*

class MyOptionMenu(OptionMenu):
    def __init__(self, master, status, *options):

        self.var = StringVar(master)
        self.var.set(status)
        OptionMenu.__init__(self, master, self.var, *options)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.master.title("Timer")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)



def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x130+300+300")
    text = Label(root, text="You are currently on: ")
    text.place(x=10, y=55)
    skills=['L1','AR','Esc']
    mymenu1 = MyOptionMenu(root, 'Select status', skills[0],skills[1],skills[2])
    mymenu1.grid(column=2, row=2)
    mymenu1.place(x=130, y=50)
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now i just need it to count how much time each status is selected and for an extra status to save the info in a csv. Also I would really appreciate a different way to add the skills to the menu, what I did seems weird.

Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign your option menu to a variable and then register a callback for any on-change events. There is a nice writeup [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm).